# When using repeated-measures ANOVA in R, what does it mean to specify Error(subject) instead of Error(subject/(A*B))?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

For a two-way repeated measures design, we can specify the model using `aov` in the following fashion:

```
aov(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + Error(subject/(iv1*iv2)), data=dataset)
```

Take the sample data from `personality-project.org` (see code below), the error term for this particular model is `Error(Subject/(Task*Valence))`.

```
datafilename="http://personality-project.org/r/datasets/R.appendix4.data"
data.ex4=read.table(datafilename,header=T)   #read the data into a table
data.ex4                                      #show the data
aov.ex4=aov(Recall~(Task*Valence)+Error(Subject/(Task*Valence)),data.ex4 )
```

What if I specify the error term instead as `Error(Subject)`. **What kind of design is this?**

From what I recall, whether you include a factor - e.g., whether `Task` and `Valence` are included - in the error term depends on whether a factor is a "within-subjects" factor. If, say, this particular recall study also included "sex" as a predictor, then we would not include it in the error term because it is a between-subjects factor. But I am not sure what it means when we don't include any of the predictors in the error term. **Is it basically an intercept-only model much like the one below specified using `lmer`**?

```
lmer(Recall~Task*Valence + (1|Subject), data=data.ex4)
```

Comment: The answer to your question is basically Yes. Your Q is related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286280 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60108 - I asked the first one, and am running a bounty on the second one. There are more related questions here too. I hope a comprehensive answer will appear in one of these threads.